# PulseEffects не обрабатывает звук с микрофона

Tags: pulseaudio

В PulseEffects при выборе источником микрофона и включении переключателей рядом с приложениями

[image: Скриншот]

PulseEffects никак не модифицирует звук и даже не отображает спектр звука в верхней части окна. ЧЯДНТ?